# Filter and display data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here was my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38745541/6672217), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38746948/6672217) is the solution i've adopted. But i have another issue.

This is how i want to display my categories but i have also sub-categories inside a category.

```
<ul>
    {{#each group in groups}}
      <li class="col-md-2">
        <ul>
          {{#each category in group}}
            <li class="dropdown-header>{{category.category}}</li>
             // <li>*Subcategories</li> this is where i want to display it
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </li>
     {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

This is how my data is structured

```
var data = [
  { category : "Cat1", subcategory : "Scat1" },
  { category : "Cat1", subcategory : "Scat2" },
  { category : "Cat2", subcategory : "Scat3" },
  { category : "Cat2", subcategory : "Scat4" },
  { category : "Cat3", subcategory : "Scat1" },
  { category : "Cat3", subcategory : "Scat2" },
  { category : "Cat4", subcategory : "Scat3" },
  { category : "Cat4", subcategory : "Scat4" },
  { category : "Cat5", subcategory : "Scat5"},
  { category : "Cat6", subcategory : "Scat6"},
  { category : "Cat6", subcategory : "Scat7"},
  { category : "Cat6", subcategory : "Scat8"}];
```

You can see, a category can have many sub-categories. So, how can i display both categories and sub-categories so that i don't get a category twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use (sub)aggregations here :

Pure Mongo

```
db.myData.aggregate([{"$group": {_id: "$category", subcategoriess: { $addToSet: "$subcategory" }}}]);
```

Gives you :

```
{ "_id" : "cat3", "subcategoriess" : [ "subcat3.2", "subcat3" ] }
{ "_id" : "cat2", "subcategoriess" : [ "subcat2" ] }
{ "_id" : "cat1", "subcategoriess" : [ "subcat1.3", "subcat1.2", "subcat1" ]}
```

Then you can iterate over your results to get the category (_id), then iterate on subcategories to get the list under each category.

Meteor :

```
var myDataCol = new Mongo.Collection('myData');
var pipeline = [
  {"$group": {_id: "$category", subcategoriess: { $addToSet: "$subcategory" } }}
];
var result = myDataCol.aggregate(pipeline);
```